# Checking if spatial references of two layers are same using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system, .net

I have two layers . Now I want to say that the spatial references of these layers are same or not ..

I am using .Net technologies in arcmap.

I have successfully got spatial reference information from layers and now I want to compare these spatial references ..

Example

sp1 , sp2

if(sp1 == sp2)

```
       give message to user that spatial references are same;
```

else

```
     give message to user that spatial references are  not same;
```

How do I know if these spatial references are same?

Comment: This is very nearly not a GIS question, since the language family, and in fact most modern language families, all have comparison operators for objects, reserving the equivalence operator for scalar values (base numeric types) and object equivalence (same object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static bool CompareSpatialRefs(ISpatialReference sourceSR, ISpatialReference targetSR)
        {
            IClone sClone = sourceSR as IClone;
            IClone tClone = targetSR as IClone;

            // first level test compares the coordinate system component  
            if (!sClone.IsEqual(tClone))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
```